Install ansible collection from private repository
How can I install using requirements.yml a collection from a gitlab repository. For example, for roles it works like this:
roles:
  - src: git+https://repo_access_token_name:token_value@url.to.repo.git
    version: 1.0.0 

but for collection from private repo it doesn't work.
I found an example of installing a collection from git, but there is no example using a token anywhere
collections:
  - name: https://github.com/organization/repo_name.git
    type: git
    version: devel

Anyone have a solution to this problem?
Anyone have a solution to this problem?

Installing a collection from a private GitLab repository using requirements.yml requires specifying a personal access token for authentication.
`collections:

name: git+https://:@gitlab.com//<repo_name>.git
type: git
version: devel`

